# Input[type="date"] autocomplete

Tags: html, autocomplete, html-input

Autocompletion is not working for `input[type="date"]` with the `autocomplete="bday"` attribute. I saw that there is no handling of `bday` in [Chromium code](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/components/autofill/core/browser/form_structure.cc) (for example).

Is there a way to do that now or that is just not implemented yet? If no then when?